# I want to use Google App Script with HTML Service to create a static HTML File, not a Web App. Can it be done?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have created a Google App Script using HTML Service to publish a Web App. But the data doesn't change frequently and I am concerned about a large number of access requests to the Web App exceeding service quotas. I really don't need a Web App, I just want to create a static HTML file that I can embed on a web page. Does anyone know how to do this?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that in Apps Script. The only way you can access the html is by doGet() method. Could you edit your post and include the content of your web app and web page? This could help other members to visualize your issue and provide better solutions. Also, Is your web page external?

Comment: Have you tried publishing without script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this:

```
function savemystinkinghtml() {
  let tmpl = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
  tmpl.msg = "I bid no Trump";
  let html = tmpl.evaluate();
  DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid).createFile('indexgas.html',html.getContent());
}
```

html: 'ah1':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><?= msg ?></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I download it to my laptop and uploaded to my website and it's works.  Admittedly it trivial but it's html.

Comment: Thanks Cooper that solved my issue.